# Explode element limit and Order By using

Tags: php, sql

I wanna make this select with ORDER BY element and Limit Element But i cant solve it .. please help me..

I am doing a php chat bot tha find something on my database and reply ..but when i am selecting data it select many data in on time . thats whyy i nedd  limit

```
 $aKeyword = explode(" ",$keyword);
      $query ="SELECT * FROM reply_key WHERE reply_key_value like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%' ";
           for($i = 1; $i < count($aKeyword); $i++) {
        if(!empty($aKeyword[$i])) {
           $query .= "OR  reply_key_value like '%" . $aKeyword[$i] . "%' ";

        }
      }
```

Comment: I don't see any `LIMIT` or `ORDER BY` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add order by id desc and then limit 1 to get the latest record, however, you can remove that "desc" if you want the oldest record.

```
$query ="SELECT * FROM reply_key WHERE reply_key_value like '%" . $aKeyword[0] . "%' " ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 1
```